# Querying 2 tables from the same database NOT working : PHP it has to be EASY but I do not see it

Tags: php, mysql

I would appreciate some help here, I am new to PHP.

I have one database with two tables ( products and categories ), as you can imagine I want to query both tables in order to have the whole picture. The problem is that it is not working. Before I used to have this info in the same table and it worked, so I guess it has something to do with querying two tables from the same PHP file.

This is the code:

```
$query = "SELECT id, stock, nombre, foto, descripcion, celda , precio
          FROM productos
          WHERE 1 = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;
$data = array();
while ($i < $num) {
  $data_id[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
  $data_stock[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"stock");
  $data_nombre[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"nombre");
  $data_foto[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"foto");
  $data_precio[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"precio");
  $data_celda[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"celda");
  $data_descripcion[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"descripcion");
  ++$i;
}

$query2 = "SELECT namec, picturec
           FROM categorias
           WHERE 1 = 1 ";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$num2 = mysql_numrows($result2);

$h = 0;
while ($h < $num2) {
  $data_celda_nombre[$h] = mysql_result($result2,$h,"namec");
  $data_celda_foto[$h] = mysql_result($result2,$h,"picturec");
  ++$h;
}

$data = array(
  "ids" => $data_id,
  "stocks" => $data_stock,
  "nombre" => $data_nombre,
  "foto" => $data_foto,
  "precio" => $data_precio,
  "celda" => $data_celda,
  "descripcion" => $data_descripcion,
  "celda_foto" => $data_celda_foto,
  "celda_nombre" => $data_celda_nombre
);

echo (json_encode($data));
```

The thing is I am not getting named and picturec , WHY?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.
Roberto L.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - I haven't really changed anything, just refactored the code so it is more "standard", if this still doesn't do what you want I will try and work out what problem you are still having.

```
$data_id = $data_stock = $data_nombre = $data_foto = $data_precio = $data_celda = $data_descripcion = $data_celda_nombre = $data_celda_foto = array();

$query = "SELECT id, stock, nombre, foto, descripcion, celda , precio
          FROM productos";
if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) die('MySQL Error: '.mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data_id[] = $row['id'];
  $data_stock[] = $row['stock'];
  $data_nombre[] = $row['nombre'];
  $data_foto[] = $row['foto'];
  $data_precio[] = $row['precio'];
  $data_celda[] = $row['celda'];
  $data_descripcion[] = $row['descripcion'];
}

$query = "SELECT namec, picturec
          FROM categorias";
if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) die('MySQL Error: '.mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data_celda_nombre[] = $row['namec'];
  $data_celda_foto[] = $row['picturec'];
}

$data = array(
  "ids" => $data_id,
  "stocks" => $data_stock,
  "nombre" => $data_nombre,
  "foto" => $data_foto,
  "precio" => $data_precio,
  "celda" => $data_celda,
  "descripcion" => $data_descripcion,
  "celda_foto" => $data_celda_foto,
  "celda_nombre" => $data_celda_nombre
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. It still does´t work. I do not why. I thought PHP didn´t allow me to query two tables (non related) on the same PHP file. Why can be still giving me so trouble?? Thanks @DaveRandom